# invalid handle injecting dll into a process using CreateRemoteThread()

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, dll-injection

I am having a problem with **CreateRemoteThread()**. I spent the last 3 days trying to figure it out and I am loosing my mind.

When I use the function **CreateRemoteThread()** the function returns **NULL** and if I use **getLastError()** I get **error 6** (which means *invalid handle*).  I was trying to inject my own dll into a notepad.exe process and I got this error and the injection did not happened. I used the following in order to get the process handle => **HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,FALSE,processID);**

Then I tried the following **HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,FALSE,GetCurrentPoccessID());** which is exact the same except the dll is being  injected into the current process being executed and **it worked**. I am kind of assuming it's a permission issue, but I have turned off all AVs including windows defender. I really want to know what is preventing me from performing the injection as everyone else seams to be able to perform the injection using a similar code. I am using a windows 11 64bits system. find below the injection code and dll code. Note

1: .dll and .exe are x64 bits

2: I am running it as adm

3: how I compiled the .dll **x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -shared -o mydll.dll mydll.cpp**

4: vs code compiler configurations:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win64",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "c:/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

[UPDATE] *I created a process and compiled it the same way I compiled the injector.cpp, I was able to inject to the process :D.. So  the issue is how I am complying the .dll * here is my system details: **64-bit operating system, ARM-based processor**

***injection.cpp***

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{if (argc < 2) {
        printf("(--) usage: dll.exe <pid>");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    DWORD PID = atoi(argv[1]);
    // Path to the target process
    const char* targetProcess = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe";

    // Path to the DLL to inject
    const char* dllPath = "C:\\Users\\fagner\\Desktop\\windowsM\\dll\\dlli2.dll";

    // Load the target process
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD, FALSE,PID);// if I replace process ID with GetCurrentProcessId() it works 
   
    if (hProcess == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    
    
    std::cout<<"id: "<<hProcess<<std::endl;

    // Allocate memory for the DLL path in the target process
    LPVOID dllPathAddress = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, strlen(dllPath) + 1, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    
    if (dllPathAddress == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return 1;
    }

    // Write the DLL path into the target process
    if (!WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, dllPathAddress, dllPath, strlen(dllPath) + 1, NULL))
    {   std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        
        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, dllPathAddress, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return 1;
    }

    // Get the address of the LoadLibraryA function
    HMODULE hKernel32 = GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32.dll"));
    
    if (hKernel32 == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, dllPathAddress, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return 1;
    }

    LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE loadLibraryAddr = (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)GetProcAddress(hKernel32, "LoadLibraryA");
    
    if (loadLibraryAddr == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, dllPathAddress, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a remote thread in the target process to load the DLL
    HANDLE hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, 0, loadLibraryAddr, dllPathAddress, 0, NULL);
   

    // when I use another process such as notepad createRemoteThread returns NULL
    if (hThread == NULL)
    {
        // when I target any other porcess GetLasterror() returns 6 which mean "invalid error"
        std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, dllPathAddress, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return 1;
    }
    

    std::cout << "DLL injected successfully!" << std::endl;

    // Wait for the remote thread to finish
    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);

    // Clean up resources
    VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, dllPathAddress, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    CloseHandle(hThread);
    CloseHandle(hProcess);

    return 0;
}
```

**dlli.dll**

````
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        // Create a file called "injected.txt" in the current directory
        std::ofstream file("injected.txt");
        if (file.is_open())
        {
            file << "DLL Injected Successfully!" << std::endl;
            file.close();
        }
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}```
````

Comment: Notepad.exe has changed in Win11, it is now a UWP app.  When you launch it then it starts the UWP flavor and quickly exits.  At which point you'll get error 6.  Calc.exe behaves this way as well.  Try another program, or [this](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/restore-old-classic-notepad-windows/)

Comment: @HansPassant Wouldn't `OpenProcess` fail if that was the issue though?  (Looks like the OP has snuck a hard coded process ID in there).

Comment: I tried using the old version of notepad and did not work. I also tried creating another process and injecting to it and got the same error 6

Comment: Start by fixing your error reporting. The documentation for [`GetLastError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) explains when calling it will produce a meaningful value. None of your calls do.

Comment: I fixed the error logging and all of them returned 0 except the one after createRemoteThread()

Comment: That's probably not the case. If `GetLastError` returns 0 for you, then you are likely calling it at a time where it won't return a meaningful value. But since only you can see your code, we cannot be sure here.

Comment: I edited the code above with the getlasterror(). Is that correct?

Comment: No, all calls to `GetLastError` are wrong, and neither one is guaranteed to produce a predictable value. The rules are rather simple: You will want to call `GetLastError` **only** under the conditions spelled out in the documentation for each API call. And when you do, you will want to call it **immediately**, with absolutely no code in between. `cout << "blah" << GetLastError();` fails this second requirement.

Comment: I have updated my post. I fixed the error logging as sugested by each of the apis being used. Then I tried to inject into a process I had compiled in the same manager as I compiled my dll and the injection worked. I figured the issue is how I am compiling the .dll, can you have a look at my post again. I added how I compile my dll and my sys details. you might be able to spot what I am doing wrong

Comment: I was able to figure it out! Windows 11 does not allow me to inject into process signed by Microsoft. I was able to inject to several other processes. Ill upvote your comment 
IInspectable as you helped me understanding getlasterror().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like windows 11 does not allow remote threads to be created into process signed by Microsoft. As I was testing dll injection in a new windows VM I only had Microsoft process to test on. I was able to inject into Several other process that weren't signed by Microsoft.

Comment: this is not true. you can create remote thread in such process. but you can not create section from unsigned file, if CIG policy active